# CakePHP Relationships over more then one Model/Table

Tags: cakephp, relationship

I'm new to learning CakePHP. I did the Blog Tutorial and am now trying to add Categories for Posts. I created Category and SubCategory Models and MySQL DB Tables and I related the Models as follows:

Post -> "belongsTo" -> SubCategory -> "belongsTo" -> Category

Post -> Subcategory is working fine and I can resolve the SubCategory Name in the View via:

```
php echo $post['SubCategory']['name'];
```

Now: How do I go one step further in the relation and get the Category Name for a Post in the Post View (via the SubCategory)? The following obviously gives me the Category ID, but not it's name:

```
php echo $post['SubCategory']['category_id'];
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [recursive parameter](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1063/recursive) for a model and go for a step 2 (2 levels of depth). This would allow you to use the category if your definition is correct. Keep in mind that it would need to fetch a lot of data and this would affect the overall performance of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [`ContainableBehavior`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html), which will help you only grab the results you really need. The first thing I *always* suggest is changing `$recursive = -1` and using Containable. This will also greatly improve the performance of your app because you will be performing less calls for data you don't actually use.

Using your example:

```
$results = $this->Post->find('all', array(
  'contain' => array(
    'SubCategory' => array(
      'Category'
    )
  )
));

// in your view foreach loop
echo $post['SubCategory']['Category']['name'];
```

Comment: After I added your Code to the Controller (and changed the echo line for the view) I am getting this:
Notice (8): Undefined index: Category [APP/View/Posts/index.ctp, line 40]

Comment: Did you debug the `$results` to make sure it joined the data?

Comment: It seems (if I got that right) that it didn't join the data. Debug output for the line in the view is 'null' and for the $results I don't see any Category data …


this is what I added to the PostsController:

     public function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        
        $this->Post->recursive = -1;
        $results = $this->Post->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
        'SubCategory' => array(
        'Category'
        )
     )
    ));
        
     }

the line in the View is the one you suggested

any idea?

Comment: Did you add the containable behavior to your `$actsAs` array?

Comment: Sorry, now I'm lost. $actsAs is for the Model right? I only made changes to the Controller and to the View. The Post Model looks like this

`class Post extends AppModel {
 public $name = 'Post';
 public $belongsTo =  'SubCategory'; `

I tried to add: `public $actsAs = array('Containable');` but without any luck.

Comment: Yes, it's the variable that attaches behaviors to the model. I assumed some knowledge on the concepts of behaviors when I posted this. After adding it and debugging the results, the data still isn't contained? You will need to add it to the SubCategory model as well. I suggest adding it to AppModel so you have access across the board.

Comment: After reading and trying I now see the joined Category data when I debug, but I can't access it in the View:
Undefined index: Category 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make sure you you pass it to the view from the controller, and then scatter some debug statements within your view to see what data you are dealing with. Also, use the DebugKit plugin to see what's been passed and to inspect it. https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit